# Bettercap filtering ARP Spoof

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, bettercap

I want to see only monitored device's visited websites not the methods and the redirects how can I filter or can I?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are seeing? I'm wondering if you are actually just looking at a packet capture.